# RabbitMq: How to correctly push data to queue, should queue be created everytime or just once?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Currently we have created method to publish message to Rabbitmq as:

```
bool PublishToQueue(string QueueName, NameValueCollection nvc)
{    
       ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;
       IConnection connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection(hostName);
       IModel model = connection.CreateModel();
       model.ExchangeDeclare(ExchangeName, ExchangeType.Direct);
       model.QueueBind(queueName, ExchangeName, queueName + "Key", null);
       model.ConfirmSelect();
       BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
       bf.AssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple;
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       bf.Serialize(ms, nvc);
       SendMessage(model, ms.ToArray(), "RabbitMQ-" + QueueName + "-Exchange", "RabbitMq-" + QueueName + "-QueueKey", nvc["id"], nvc["category"]);
}
```

Though queue is idempotent so is not created again. But i believe its not correct to initialize connection, model, exchange and its bindings again and again for each message.

Can someone tell me what is the best way to separate the initialization of queue and sending messages?

Note: This is simplified code. I have not included fallback codes, all variable initialization like ExchangeName etc.

Comment: I don't understand the question and your example looks like it's just for practice, since the publishing side should not care about queues.  Are you asking about your example? Or for consumers that are running all the time or something else?

Comment: This is publisher code we are using currently. Looks bad code to me as we are creating model, queue everytime which makes no sense. Queue should  be created just once.
I want to check some good producer code that first create model, the give functionality to send message. Also, same thing for cosumer. It would be great if example has performance oriented code. If it covers, dead letter/error retry, that would be added bonus.

Comment: You're missing the point - it's not the problem that you are creating the queue every time, the problem is creating it at all on the publishing side. Have you looked at the tutorial? https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html

Comment: even in the example, before publishing message, they are creating new connection, then new channel, then queue is declared. Finally they send using channel.BasicPublish to send the message. Now from an application do we need to do this for all messages we publish i.e create new conection, channel, queue every time?

Comment: Once again, you **never** have to declare/create queue when publishing, **not even once**. For the connection and channel, once is sufficient.

Comment: I am getting confused here. "Final code of our NewTask.cs class:", in this example in article https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-dotnet.html they use "channel.QueueDeclare" & this method is used to declare a queue. After declaring queue, they are using "channel.BasicPublish" to publish the message.

Comment: I'm sorry... I see why you're confused. You may notice that the same queue declaration is done on the consumer side. That's because in this example, direct exchange is used, where routing key is the name of the queue. So the parameter in publishing method is **the routing key**. There is no need to declare the queue on publishing side, because the publisher (usually) doesn't care who receives his messages.

Comment: If we want to push rabbitmq message on click of button and we want to use direct exchange, how can i avoid these redundant declarations again and again? Any suitable example for production application where several messages would be published through button-click/API/crons?

Answer (score 0):

I use a single class that is responsible for declaring exchanges, queues and creating bindings. It has static dictionaries for storing the names of exchanges and queues already declared and bound. Before making a declaration, it performs a check in these static dictionaries (in a thread safe way) to see if it declared it already, so only does the declaration once during the lifetime of the application.